# Copy a file from one domain to another (not a local file)

Tags: c#, file, copy, impersonation

I`ve seen here and around copying of files with impersonate only from a local folder to a remote computer.
I have a directory on one domain (exttest 10.231.31.11) and I wish to copy it to another domain (extmun 10.239.211.12). Each domain is of course with its own credentials.
Is it possible to do it via code with out a local temp folder?

I`m currently using this method and a temp folder to copy from and to copy to

```
if (LogonUser(username, domain, password, 9, 0, ref admin_token) != 0)
{
    using (var wic = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(admin_token)) { ... }
    ....
}
```

Thanks